# Interact Object to check if value exist using Includes

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to compare whether a value exists via Array.prototype.includes() but it is not working as expected.

See below

```
async loadFilterCheckboxState() {
    // If filterString = Cliente=6&Recrutador=45,37&Negociador=45,43,8
    // Cliente and value 6 will be checked in the filterList.filters
    // Recrutador and value 45,37 will be checked in the filterList.filters
    // Negociador and value 45,43,8 will be checked in the filterList.filters
    // return if filterString is empty or ?
    if (this.filterString === "?" || this.filterString === "") {
      console.log("filterString is empty");
      return;
    }
    const _filterString = this.filterString;
    const _filterList = this.filterList;

    const _filterArray = _filterString.split("&");
    _filterArray.forEach((filter) => {
      const _filterName = filter.split("=")[0];
      const _filterValue = filter.split("=")[1];
      const _filterValueArray = _filterValue.split(",");
      const _filterItem = _filterList.find((item) => item.name === _filterName);
      _filterItem.filters.forEach((item) => {
        console.log("SEARCHING: " + _filterValueArray + " IN " + item.value);
        if (_filterValueArray.includes(item.value)) {
          item.checked = true;
          console.log("Match: " + item.checked);
        } else {
          console.log("Not Match");
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

[image: Console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to see the data in `_filterList` it's not possible to say for sure, but having played around with your code I suspect this will be a type mismatch. `Array.includes()` will use strict equality to compare values and so if your `_filterList` has numbers rather than strings, then you will need to do a type conversion before calling `Array.includes()`.

Below is the code I tested with. As you can see, in cases where the value of a filter was a string the code found the match, and in cases where the value of a filter was a number it did not:

```js
const _filterString = 'Cliente=6&Recrutador=45,37&Negociador=45,43,8';
const _filterList = [
  {name: 'Cliente', filters: [{value: '6', checked: ''}]},
  {name: 'Recrutador', filters: [{value: 45, checked: ''}]},
  {name: 'Negociador', filters: [{value: '8', checked: ''}]}
];

const _filterArray = _filterString.split("&");
_filterArray.forEach((filter) => {
  const _filterName = filter.split("=")[0];
  const _filterValue = filter.split("=")[1];
  const _filterValueArray = _filterValue.split(",");
  const _filterItem = _filterList.find((item) => item.name === _filterName);
  _filterItem.filters.forEach((item) => {
    console.log("SEARCHING: " + _filterValueArray + " IN " + item.value);
    if (_filterValueArray.includes(item.value)) {
      item.checked = true;
      console.log("Match: " + item.checked);
    } else {
      console.log("Not Match");
    }
  });
});
```

Results:

> SEARCHING: 6 IN 6
> Match: true
> SEARCHING: 45,37 IN 45
> Not Match
> SEARCHING: 45,43,8 IN 8
> Match: true

Comment: Yes you are right, in _filterList "value" is number and _filterString is string[].